# TypeError: object.__new__(int) is not safe, use int.__new__()

Tags: python, metaclass

While reading this: [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python), I am learning to use `__new__` using the following snippet:-

```
class a(object):
    pass

a.__new__(int,'abcdef',(int,),{})
```

There could be some problem in calling `__new__` using `a.`. But, I get the following error, the meaning of which I do not understand:-

`TypeError: object.__new__(int) is not safe, use int.__new__()`

If there is something to do with the usage of `__new__`, I can ammend that by reading some books. But, can someone please explain why this message comes:

`object.__new__(int) is not safe, use int.__new__()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put simply, prior to 2.6 - `object.__new__` **ignored** arguments... Now it actually may do something with them... So the warning is that something different may happen.

This post [Any ideas about the best work around for __new__ losing its arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028321/any-ideas-about-the-best-work-around-for-new-losing-its-arguments) - has a much more detailed explanation.

You probably also want to be looking at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type

Knowing what's possible with all the *meta* stuff in Python is great, but just as a warning, I wouldn't get too hung up about it - as I've seen some really "clever" solutions, that are just  monstrosities...