# What is the downside of using object.__new__ in __new__?

Tags: python

Coding exception classes, I came across this error:

`TypeError: object.__new__(A) is not safe, use Exception.__new__()`

There's a similar question posted here:
[TypeError: object.__new__(int) is not safe, use int.__new__()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952184/typeerror-object-new-int-is-not-safe-use-int-new). So `__new__` was deprecated for the following reason:

[[Python-Dev] `__new__` deprecation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/076854.html)

> Guido van Rossum
>
> *"The message means just what it says. :-) There's no point in calling
>   `object.__new__()` with more than a class parameter, and any code that
>   did so was just dumping those args into a black hole."*

But the warning in 3.3 that I get "is not safe" is scary. I try to understand the implication of using `object.__new__`, let's consider this example:

```
>>> class A(Exception):
...     def __new__(cls, *args):
...             return object.__new__(A)
...
>>> A()
TypeError: object.__new__(A) is not safe, use Exception.__new__()
```

Fails miserably. Another Example:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __new__(cls, *args):
...             return object.__new__(A)
...
>>>
>>> A()
<__main__.A object at 0x0000000002F2E278>
```

works fine. Although, `object` is a builtin class just like `Exception` with respect to their roles, they share the trait of being builtin-classes. Now with `Exception`, the first example raises `TypeError`, but with `object`, it does not?

**(a) What are the downsides of using `object.__new__` that made Python to raise the error (`TypeError:...is not safe...`) in the first Example?**

**(b) What sort of checking Python performs before to calling `__new__`? Or: What is the condition that makes Python raise the error in the first example?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no problem in calling `object.__new__`, but there is a problem in not calling `Exception.__new__`.

`Exception` class was designed in such way that it is crucial that its `__new__` must be called, so it complains if that is not done.

There was a question why this happens only with built-in classes. Python in fact does it with every class which is programmed to do that.

Here is a simplified poor-mans implementation of the same mechanism in a custom class:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        rtn = object.__new__(cls)
        rtn.new_called = True
        return rtn

    def __init__(self):
        assert getattr(self,'new_called',False), \
            "object.__new__ is unsafe, use A.__new__"

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

And now:

```
>>> A()
<__main__.A object at 0x00000000025CFF98>

>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
AssertionError: object.__new__ is unsafe, use A.__new__
```

---

As a side note, this example from the question actually has two errors:

```
>>> class A(Exception):
...     def __new__(cls, *args):
...             return object.__new__(A)
```

The first is that `__new__` is called on `object`, thus ignoring `Exception.__new__`.

The other, just as severe is that `A` is passed to `__new__` instead of `cls`, which hinders all classes inherited from `A`.

See this example:

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        return object.__new__(A)  # The same erroneous line, without Exception

class B(A):
    pass
```

And now `B()` does not create an instance of `B`:

```
>>> B()
<__main__.A object at 0x00000000025D30B8>
```

Comment: I just realized the mechanism is coded in `object.__new__`. Look at [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9a98b59f1f3bc518f0ba89ff667083c6). That is, `object.__new__` raises the `TypeError`. Very reasonable now to say "not safe." Although, overriding `Exception.__new__` in a subclass won't raise an error, even if `Exception.__new__` isn't called inside `Subclass.__new__`, this is equivalently dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `object.__new__(A)` returns an instance of `A`, but does so without calling `Exception.__new__()` if it is defined.

Comment: _"but does so without calling `Exception.__new__()` if it is defined._ This wouldn't be a problem because we defined `__new__` lower (in the subclass). This has nothing to do with whether Exception.__new__ will be called or not. If we have two superclasses each having `__new__` method : `C(A,B)`, then the left-most `__new__` will be called, that is `A.__new__` and `B.__new__` will not be called. Could you elaborate with an example?

Comment: What you raise is a separate problem, solved by either calling both `A.__new__()` and `B.__new__()` explicitly, or by using `super` and ensuring all the ancestor classes use it, too. Failing to call `Exception.__new__` is a big problem, if you miss `Exception`-specific configuration and plan on passing your object to someone expecting a properly configured instance of `Exception`.

Comment: I do see your point: (replacing `__new__` with another `__new__` may skip some or all the crucial configurations required for an object during creation).

Comment: If you consider [this code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49e7ccb7e83e02c773d64b8913d95eff) you will notice that Python raises (`TypeError:... is not safe...`) only for builtin classes. You can see from [the code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49e7ccb7e83e02c773d64b8913d95eff) that class `A` has its own `__new__` and class `B` inherits directly from `A` and uses `object.__new__(*b)` in its `__new__`. This doesn't raise any error when run in Python 3.3. Why Python raises the exception for builtin classes only, not user defined classes too?